# Exception when inserting in deque using subscript [] notation in cpp

Tags: deque

I am getting "out of index" error when inserting in deque using subscript. Trying to add at index 0, but when using deq.push_front() I didn't get any out of bound error message. Can't use push_front() as I need to override the data at index 0 for few iterators and then push it to the front. I am compiling on Visual Studio 10, but on Gcc compiler it works fine.Has anyone came across this problem before.
Here is the code

```
class My
{
    struct To
    {  
     // some implementations
    };
    struct From
    {
        // some implementations
    };
public:
   void foo(Two _par);
   void create();
private:
   Two two;
   std::deque<Two> _dtwo;
};

void My::create()
{
   // populate struct Two here and then pass it to foo()
   foo(two);
}
void My::foo(Two _par)
{
   // populate std::deque<Two> here
   _dtwo[0] = _par; // out of bound error
  // but if I use  _dtwo.push_front(_par) no issue

}
```